# compile error after upgrading to Java 7: package sun.security.pkcs11 does not exist

Tags: java, security, pkcs#11

I just upgraded from Java 6 to Java 7 SDK and am now getting the following error in my ant build:

error: package sun.security.pkcs11 does not exist
        Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(is);

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. I can compile fine if I switch back to Java 6, but that is not an option any longer.  I haven't had much luck finding a solution online.  Anybody knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is because you depended on an internal (non-API) package of JDK.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412802/sun-security-couldnt-find-after-upgrading-java

Answer (score 4):

You will have to convert your application to use APIs which are not restricted. The compiler will warn you quite strictly when you have done such a thing -- this is the consequence of proceeding in the face of those warnings.

See [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: A great link that explains _EXACTLY_ why the OP should have never used that package in the first place!

Comment: ok, dont' use internal / deprecated API. now : what's the official package equivalent to sun.security.pkcs11 ?

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem and i solve it by installing the 32-bit JDK insteade of 64-bit and sure it will work .

Answer (score 3):

The API has not been released by oracle [oracle bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7196276) and the answers by tom and yassering are both corect.

Answer (score 2):

Since sunPKCS11 support is not there in Windows 64 bit, i am assuming that you are using windows 64 bit just for build environment and your runtime might be a linux or other supported environments.

If the above is true, then inorder to make the build work, copy the sunpkcs11.jar from a 32 bit jdk and copy to a 64 bit jdk under jre\lib\ext. This worked for me.

Or, alternatively wait for jdk8 where its fixed.

Answer (score -2):

I'm having the same error.

```
Only a type can be imported. sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_AES_CTR_PARAMS resolves to a package
```

I have windows 7 x64 with jdk 7x64 installed then replaced with jdk 7x32. I also made sure that my JAVA_HOME was set to the new jdk installation. I get the same problem when I run my application.

Comment: this is not an answer